# Ruby on rails - loop through two combined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two unrelated tables that I need to loop through simultaneously and call on different attributes of each. So at the moment I have (using generic names for simplicity):

```
<% @combined = Tableone.all + Tabletwo.all %>
<% @combined.each do |c| %>
<% if c.is_a?(Tableone) %> 
     do some code....
<% elsif c.is_a?(Tabletwo) %>
     do other code...
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

So at the moment the elsif block is not being reached and only the Tableone results are showing. How can I get around this and loop through both tables?

EDIT: Here's the full code.

```
<% @subcategory = Subcategory.all %>
<% @product = Product.all %>
<% @ps = Product.all + Subcategory.all %>

<% @ps.each do |ps| %>

    <% if (ps).is_a?(Product) %>
    <% if (ps).display_on_home_page and !(ps).is_highlight_product and !(ps == '..') %>
        <% if ps.price_from %>
            <div class="column_entry">
           <div class="product_special">
            <span class="a">From Only</span>
            <span class="b"><%= number_to_currency(ps.price,:unit=>'€') %></span></div>
                <%= link_to image_tag(ps.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(ps.id), :controller=>'products' %>
            </div>
         <% else %>
            <div class="column_entry">
            <div class="product_special">
            <span class="a">Only</span>
            <span class="b"><%= number_to_currency(ps.price,:unit=>'€') %></span>
            </div>
            <%= link_to image_tag(ps.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(ps.id), :controller=>'products' %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
    <% elsif (ps).is_a?(Subcategory) %>
        <%= "Reached elsif" %>
        <% if (ps).display_on_home_page and !(ps).is_highlight_product and !(ps == '..') %>
        <div class="column_entry">
            <%= link_to image_tag(ps.image_attachment.url(:normal_page_size)), subcategories_content_url(ps.id), :controller=>'subcategories' %>
        </div>                          
    <% end %>                                                           
    <% end %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Even if that code did work as expected, you wouldn't be looping through those simultaneously. You'd loop through Tableone, then loop through Tabletwo. It is the equivalent of `Tableone.all.each .. Tabletwo.all.each`.

Comment: @DamienRoche Oh okay I'll edit the title of my question. What's stopping the loop from reaching Tabletwo then?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that comment as a nitpick. My point was, why loop through these tables combined when you can just loop through them separately? I couldn't say what the problem is without the code in front of me. The only possibility I can see so far is that `Tabletwo` doesn't have any rows.

Comment: No problem, I was looping through them separately but I was asked to display the results of the combined tables randomly not one table then the other. There are definitely rows in Tabletwo but I'll put the full code up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally got it figured out. The problem was that @ps was being defined in the HTML. Defining @ps in the controller like so:

```
@ps = Products.where(:display_on_home_page=>true) + Subcategory.where(:display_on_home_page=>true)
```

means that the loop will see both products and subcategories. I'm not entirely sure why this is other than, by convention, the variable declaration should have been in the controller.